# Robot Framework for loop - selector always returning same element

Tags: selenium, for-loop, robotframework

I have an unordered list, from which I need to get the title from each element.

```
li class="chart-flyout-option" ng-repeat="option in filteredOptions = ($ctrl.options | filter: { value: $ctrl.filterText })" ng-class="{'chart-flyout-option-selected':  option.key == $ctrl.selectedOption.key}"><a class="chart-flyout-link" ng-bind-html="option.value | highlight:$ctrl.filterText" title="HERE IS TITLE 1" ng-click="$ctrl.select(option.key, $event)" data-key="126">HERE IS TITLE 1</a></li>
```

Next element would be similar, but assume - HERE IS TITLE 2

I have a for loop, which looks like this:

```
Get Flyout Entry Child Links
    ${numflyoutentries}=    Get Number Chart Flyout Entries
    ${numflyoutentries}=    Evaluate    ${numflyoutentries} + ${1}
    : FOR    ${entry}    IN RANGE    1    ${numflyoutentries}
    \    ${label}=    Get Text     class:chart-flyout-link
    \    Log     ${label}
```

However this only ever returns the text "HERE IS TITLE 1".

Why doesn't my selector increment?

Comment: Why doesn't the selector increment? Because they aren't designed to increment.

Comment: I possibly framed the question incorrectly. The selector doesn't pick the next element, although when I've added some debug all elements in the list are being reached.